# Is this a good user control layout for WPF?

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

Below is a code snippet of how I have been laying out my WPF control XAML. I do it mainly because I get intellisense in the editor and I can change the implementation of the viewmodel and push the layout into a resource file.

However, I am not sure whether you gurus have a better insight into why I should not do this?

I'm just after a critique really.

```
<UserControl.Resources>
<ResourceDictionary>
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        <ResourceDictionary Source="../../Styles/BaseStyles.xaml"/>
    </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>

    <DataTemplate x:Key="LayoutRoot" 
                  DataType="{x:Type ns:IViewModel}">

        <Grid Height="200" Width="300">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

            <Label Content="Some Label" Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" Margin="5, 0" 
                   Target="{Binding ElementName=Lcb1}"/>

            <endorsements:LimitComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Lcb1" 
                            Limit="{Binding SomeData}" />

            <Label Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="Some Other Label" 
                   Style="{StaticResource BoldLabel}" Margin="5, 0" Target={Binding ElementName=Lcb2/>

            <endorsements:LimitComboBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" x:Name="Lcb2" 
                            Limit="{Binding SomeOtherData}" />

            <StackPanel Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" HorizontalAlignment="Right" Grid.ColumnSpan="2">
                <Button Content="OK" Command="{Binding ApplyCommand}" IsDefault="True"/>
                <Button Content="Cancel" IsCancel="True"/>
            </StackPanel>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

Comment: Could you explain how is this user control meant to be used?

Comment: It not so much about what the control does, but more about how to layout the markup. Instead of putting the markup directly into the body, I am placing it in a data template which may or may not be in the resources tag, then using a content presenter to display.

Answer (score 3):

There are 2 things that I could critisize on your code with the information you gave us:

1. Don't load style resources inside the usercontrol. Let the application hold control over how to style a usercontrol
2. Try not to use a grid in this context, because it prevents the control from adopting itself to new sizes of the window. StackPanels and Dockpanel are much better for this

Comment: How exactly would another kind of panel help here? I think that `Grid` is ideal for this kind of label-value UIs.

Comment: Well it depends where you will integrate that user control. If you know that that part of the UI never will get resized then you are fine using grid yes.